# compile error when creating an "instead of" trigger for a view

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've created an "instead of" trigger for a simple view that only does select * on a table and a trigger that does nothing (I wanted to minimize the problem):

```
create or replace view tmp(id, nazwa, nip, adres, zalega, punkty) as
select * from klient

create or replace trigger tmp_trg
instead of insert
on tmp
for each row
begin

end;
```

The view is created.
Then when I want do declare this trigger sql developer returns error:

Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:     begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with 'an identifier'    'a double-quoted delimited-identifier' 'a bind variable' <<    close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe

Comment: Note: if you just want to stop people inserting into your view, just revoke the INSERT privileges from the view.

Answer (score 5):

just add "null;" between the begin and the end.

Comment: It didnt help. When i had the real stuff in the trigger (before minimizing the problem) the error code was the same. So having trigger that does nothing is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> a trigger that does nothing (I wanted to minimize the problem):

I'm not sure I understand why you need a trigger if it does nothing ?

To answer, there isn't a valid PL/SQL statement in your trigger code block, add a `NULL` to make it a valid block and have no action.

```
create or replace trigger tmp_trg
instead of insert
on tmp
for each row
begin
NULL;
end;
```

Comment: When I created the real trigger which was doing stuff, it caused the same problem.
So I've tried to declare a trigger with nothing inside to check if it will casuse the same problem and it did. It helps in searching the cause of the problem because we dont have to check if the syntax inside the trigger caused the problem. Minimizing problems works this way if you dont know. I thought it is be obvious.